# Iterating over nested array object in angular 4 component is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

When I try to iterate over nested array object using below code, it is not working. it is throwing error "undefined" any issues in Typescript or angular4?

```
import { Process, Event } from "./process";

export class ProcessComponent {

 process: Process;

someMethod() {

    for(let val of this.process.events) {
        console.log(val.notes); // throwing error in console showing undefined.
 }
}
```

process.ts

```
export class Process {
    id: number;
    includeSaturdays: boolean;
    includeSundays: boolean;
    events: Event[];    
}

export class Event {
    id: number;
    date: number;   
    notes: string;
}
```

example data :

```
{
    "id": 1572734,
    "includeSaturdays": false,
    "includeSundays": false,
    "events": {
        "event": [
            {
                "id": 1587532,
                "date": 1483209000000,                
                "notes": "New year"
            },
            {
                "id": 1587533,
                "date": 1495909800000,
                "notes": "Memorial day"
            }]
 }
}
```

Comment: in your example data, events is not an array, is a key/value map, where the key event is mapped to an array of objects

Comment: `for(let val of this.process.events.event)` possibly you mean this?

Comment: try this. this should work. `process: Process[];` you have json object and not  array of objects.

Comment: I tried it is not working.

Comment: It is taking value as undefined. I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data structure, you might want to do something like this instead.

```
someMethod() {

 this.process.events.event.map(item => console.log(item.notes))

}
```

You're trying to work with an array of objects, not one large one, so `map()` seems more suited to this task.

Comment: No. still it is not working. I have no idea why it is not able to fetch nested object elements.